# How to pass consecutive multiple arguments and enter to a command inside shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have created a simple shell script. In this script one command require user input as 1 1 1 ENTER ENTER ENTER ENTER etc.

How can i pass these user inputs to script?

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass three lines consisting of the string "1" followed by an arbitrary number of blank lines to the command `cmd`, you can do:

```
yes "" | sed -e 1,3s/^/1/ | cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

What shell are you using?

Typically ,You can pass user input using read.
Here is an example using bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ask User to Input Data
echo "Enter your Number"

#Store user input to a variable
read userNumber

#Process user input. In this case display it back
echo "You entered $userNumber"
```